# CASE Statement to add to WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I use this case statement in SQL Server?

```
declare @isnot tinyint
select @isnot = 1

select top 100 * 
from Employee 
where EmployeeID > 1  
  and case 
         when @isnot = 1 
            then (EmployeeName = 'Brian') 
            else (EmployeeName = 'Anie')
end
```

and what if the query like this?

```
declare @isnot tinyint
select @isnot = 1 -- option : 0 and 1

select top 100 * 
       from Employee 
        where EmployeeID > 1 
        case 
            when @isnot = 1 
            then (and EmployeeName = 'Brian') 
            else '' -- blank
    end
```

i dont want to use any subquery or something like that.

Comment: you are just missing `END` at the end... you need to end the `CASE` statement with `END`

Comment: @Aominè i want to add case to my where statement so it will automaticly add Employee = 'Bran' or Employee = 'Anie'

Comment: It's generally much better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of case expressions in WHERE and ON clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @isnot tinyint
select @isnot = 1

SELECT top 100 * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE 
EmployeeID > 1  AND 
EmployeeName =
             CASE @isnot 
             WHEN 1 
             THEN 'Brian' 
             ELSE 'Anie'
             END
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my real question in this thread is on the second question

Comment: (@isnot  = 1 AND EmployeeName  = 'Brian') OR @isnot <> 1

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a value binary check (the code only cares about value 1 or not 1) you could also use [IIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) which makes for shorter syntax.

```
DECLARE @isnot tinyint = 1

SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM Employee 
WHERE EmployeeID > 1 AND
EmployeeName = IIF(@isnot = 1, 'Brian', 'Anie')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the key to this, you need END to finish the CASE statement and also EmployeeName begins the AND...so:

EITHER

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID > 1
AND EmployeeName = CASE WHEN @isnot = 1 THEN 'Brian' ELSE 'Anie' END
```

OR

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM Employee WHERE EmployeeID > 1
AND EmployeeName = CASE WHEN @isnot = 1 THEN 'Brian' ELSE '' END
```

Answer (score 0):

No case statement

```
WHERE EmployeeID > 1 
    AND (EmployeeName == 'Brian' AND @isnot = 1
        OR EmployeeName == 'Anie')
```